# VB.net (VS 2005) User Class access to public variable of maindisplay.master.vb

Tags: vb.net, master-pages

I am attempting to access a public member of the Master page class from a User Class.

In my master page, I have:

```
Partial Class MainDisplay  
Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

Public Shared m_test As Integer
  ...
```

In my User Class, I have:

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Web.UI.MasterPage  
Public Class mytest

Public Function getValue() As Integer

    Dim iRet As Integer = 0

    iRet = Master.m_test  ' how do i get access to the public member**

End Function
End Class
```

How do I get access to m_test from the user class?

thanks

Comment: VTC: there's not enough code there to tell if `Master` is an instance of `MainDisplay` or not. The answer to give is divergent on this.

Answer (score 0):

My VB is a little rusty, but the first thing I notice is that the class with the shared member is called `MainDisplay` but you're referencing it as `Master` when you try to access the shared member.  Does it work if you reference it as `MainDisplay` (note that you may need to fully-qualify the namespace or import the namespace in the `mytest` class file).

Comment: your rustiness is probably better than my vb since I'm new.  I'm uncertain as how to reference the Master page.  Either Master or MainDisplay does nothing for me.

Comment: @Neato: Is the `mytest` class in the same namespace as the `MainDisplay` class?  If not, you'll need to add an `Imports` line at the top of the `mytest` class file for the namespace that contains `MainDisplay` (which very likely is not `System.Web.UI.MasterPage` or anything under `System`, but rather a namespace specific to your project/code).

Comment: On a side note, does `Imports System.Web.UI.MasterPage` even compile?  That's a class, not a namespace.

Comment: mytest is not in the same namespace as MainDisplay.  MainDisplay inherits from system.web.ui.masterpage.  It isn't in a namespace as i can determine.

Comment: @Neato: It's not wrapped in a namespace directive?  It's definitely in a namespace, it's just a question of what that namespace is.  If you're using Visual Studio then it should be able to suggest the correct namespace as a response to the compiler error that a reference to `MainDisplay` would generate.  If there's no namespace in the `MainDisplay` class file, I suggest explicitly adding one.  Favor explicit over implicit.

Comment: let me investigate further. your suggestions are helpful.  Why do I have a -1 for my question?

Comment: @Neato: Beats me, I didn't vote on it.  I guess somebody thought it was unclear.  Voting on Stack Overflow is anonymous, so don't take it personally.